How async function is getting executed before second .then()?
I'm experiencing an unexpected order of execution when using Promises and async/await in JavaScript. Here’s the code snippet:
let a = "Hanzala"
let newPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let error = false
    if (!error) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Async Task");
            resolve(a)
        }, 1000)
    } else {
        reject("Error")
    }
});


newPromise
.then((data) => {
    console.log("Async resolved",data)
    return data.toUpperCase()
})
.then((data) => {
    console.log(data+" from second then")
})
.catch((e) => {
    console.log(e + " Async rejected");
});

(async () => {
    try {
        const res = await newPromise
        console.log(res+ " from async await")
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error+"Error form async");
    }
})();

The Output is :
Async Task
Async resolved Hanzala
Hanzala from async await
HANZALA from second then

Question:
Why does the output order differ from my expectation? Specifically, why does the log "Hanzala from async await" appear before "HANZALA from second then"?
expected Output:
Async Task
Async resolved Hanzala
HANZALA from second then
Hanzala from async await

Additional Information:

I understand that both Promises and async/await use the microtask queue, but I’m unclear on how their execution order is determined in this scenario.
Any insights into how the event loop handles this would be appreciated.


It's a really good idea to avoid mixing await and .then() chains.

This doesn't really have anything to do with async/await. You'd get the same behaviour if you had used newPromise.then(…) instead of await newPromise.

"expected Output" - can you explain why exactly you expected that? There is nothing in your code that defines one to happen after the other.

With const res = await newPromise you only wait for the Promise create by:
let newPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let error = false
    if (!error) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Async Task");
            resolve(a)
        }, 1000)
    } else {
        reject("Error")
    }
});

because that is the Promise stored in newPromise, and not the Promise returned at the end of the chain from:
.catch((e) => {
    console.log(e + " Async rejected");
});

To get the exact same result you would need to do something like this:


let a = "Hanzala"
let newPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let error = false
    if (!error) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Async Task");
            resolve(a)
        }, 1000)
    } else {
        reject("Error")
    }
});

let anotherPromise = newPromise
.then((data) => {
    console.log("Async resolved",data)
    return data.toUpperCase()
})
.then((data) => {
    console.log(data+" from second then")
})
.catch((e) => {
    console.log(e + " Async rejected");
});

(async () => {
    try {
        const res = await newPromise;
        await anotherPromise;
        console.log(res+ " from async await")
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error+"Error form async");
    }
})();



This stores the result of the generated Promise in another variable. And you can then wait for both, in the order you would like.
As a note:
This way of structuring code is not the best way, first of all in one "unit" (project, module or at least per file basis) you should not mix await/async and then. While storing Promises in variables is not necessarily wrong, you should take care that none of these are orphans.

But the updated version of your code changes the newPromise variable to be the final value returned by the .then() chain, which does not resolve to the original value of the promise but rather to undefined. This gives output as:
Async Task     Async resolved Hanzala          HANZALA from second then           undefined from async await

@HanzalaSarguroh Ah yes I missed that part. It looked like only the ordering is relevant.

@HanzalaSarguroh Updated the answer.
